# Data is not being saved in the Database when added from the frontend (MERN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I have been doing this simple MERN project with just the CRUD operations. I use MERN for this project. Now I have a problem in saving the data received from the front end to MongoDB. It is found that the data successfully reaches the backend but fails to save into the database. However, when I tried to POST data through Postman, the database gets updated. But when I try to add data from the frontend fields, the data doesn't get populated in DB. There are no errors shown in the console.

**Here is the App.js code (frontend - ReactJS)**

```
    import {useState} from 'react' 
    import './App.css';
    import Axios from 'axios';
    
    function App() {
    
      const [name, setName] = useState(""); 
      const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
      const [unit, setUnit] = useState("");
      const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
    
      const addProduct = ()=>{
        Axios.post('http://localhost:4000/items', {
          name: name,
          quantity: quantity,
          unit: unit,
          price: price
        }).then(()=>
                {console.log("Item addded successfully");
      });
    };
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
    
        <div className="itemCreator">
          <h1>Create Item</h1>
            <input className="inputField" type="text" placeholder="Product Name" onChange ={(event)=>{
              setName(event.target.value);
            }}></input>
    
            <input className="inputField" type="number" placeholder="Total Quantity" onChange ={(event)=>{
              setQuantity(event.target.value);
            }}></input>
    
            <select className="inputField" name="unit" onChange ={(event)=>{
              setUnit(event.target.value);
            }}>
              <option value="KG">KG</option>
              <option value="Litre">Litre</option>
              <option value="Pcs">Pcs</option>
            </select>
    
            <input className="inputField" type="number" placeholder="Price"onChange ={(event)=>{
              setPrice(event.target.value);
            }}></input>
            <button className="submit-btn" onClick={addProduct}>Add</button>
        </div>
    
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

**Here's the app.js (backend - ExpressJS)**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const itemsRoute = require('./routes/items');
const notificationRoute = require('./routes/notifications')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/items', itemsRoute);  
app.use('/notifications',notificationRoute);

//Connecting DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:admin@ibmproject.xxfyd.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority',(event)=>{
  console.log("Connected to DB"); 
}).catch(e=> console.log(e));

app.listen(4000);
```

**And here is the item.js (backend - ExpressJS)**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Item = require('../models/ItemModel')// importing item model


router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  Item.find()
    .then(data=>{
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(e=>{
      res.json({message: e});
    })
})

router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
  console.log('post function is working');

  const newItem = new Item({
    name: req.body.name,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    unit: req.body.unit,
    price: req.body.price
  }) //creating a new item


  newItem.save() // saving the created item to DB. This works in Postman but not when data is entered from front end
    .then(data=>{
      res.json(data);
      console.log('item saved') 
    })
    .catch(e=>{
      res.json({message: e});
  })
})

router.delete('/:id',(req,res)=> {
  Item.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id})
  .then(data =>{
    res.json(data);
  })
  .catch(e=>{
    res.json({message: e});
  })
})

// router.patch('/',(req,res)=>{
//   res.json({data: "Yes, you can Patch!"})
// })


router.patch('/:id',(req,res)=>{
  Item.updateOne({_id: req.params.id},{
    $set: {                                       // setting the new value over the requested values
      name: req.body.name,
      quantity: req.body.quantity,
      unit: req.body.unit,
      price: req.body.price}
  })
  .then(data =>{
    res.json(data); // sending updated data to DB
  })
  .catch(e=>{
    res.json({message: e});
  })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: try printing value of `req.body.name` and other values in req.body  in `router.post("/")`. Check if they are not undefined. also add `console.log(e)` in `.catch(e)` after saving post. It will console the error in console.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the req.body.unit is causing this problem. I tried making it's input type text, which solved the problem. But is there a way we can select and pass the data in dropdown menu?